# Append query strings through links, buttons, menus etc

Tags: javascript, wordpress, query-string

I have been using this javascript on my Wordpress site for sometime now and it has been working fine until a day or two ago, I did not change anything that would affect this. It still works fine on my test site so I cannot figure out why it stopped working. I am looking for any solution to the problem. Basically, agents are given a unique query string to give so when their customers visit the site, they will get commission. When a visitor goes from page to page or clicks the quote button (going to external portal), the query string passes page to page and to the external portal.
site.com/?group=agent123 - the script is loading. Firefox error is *href is undefined*. Chrome shows error regarding *indexOf*, line noted below fixed the error but did not make the script work... I am not a script writer so I cannot figure it out.

```
var index = window.location.href.indexOf('?') 
    if(index != -1){
        var querystring = window.location.href.slice(index + 1)
        var tagA = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // this next line fixed the error hence allowing other 
    // broken scripts after this to work again but script does not work 
    // for appending the query strings...   
if (href !== undefined)
            
        for(var i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++){
            var href = tagA[i].getAttribute('href');

            href += (href.indexOf('?') != -1)? '&' : '?';
            href += querystring;

            tagA[i].setAttribute('href', href);
            
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `if (href !== undefined)` in `for(var i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++){` after declaration of variable.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++){
        var href = tagA[i].getAttribute('href'); 
        if (href !== undefined) {
               href += (href.indexOf('?') != -1)? '&' : '?';
               href += querystring;

               tagA[i].setAttribute('href', href);
        }

    
    }
}
```

Best regards.